# Getting the all files in .zip file while uploading files

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, uploadify

I'm trying to use `uploadify` control in MVC3. It works fine for uploading files.

Here is my problem:

How can i get the files in .zip file ?. Let me clear the question.

Here is a zip file (say : `images.zip`). It contains 3 `jpeg` files.

Now if i upload the `images.zip` file using upload control on my view page i need to get all the image files in the zip file.

If i uplaod `images.zip` file it should show all the images like this

[image]

I dont know how to get the files and how to start.

I've searched google but didnt get any clue about this.

How to get this? If any `Jquery` or `Javascript` code is avaliable please post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use .NET 4.5, there is a new [ZipFile class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx) that will let you get properties of a zipped archive.

If you're under 4.5, you will need a 3rd party zip file library, like [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) or [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).

Comment: does ZipFile Class supports unzipping the files ?

Comment: the ZipArchive class has a property `Entries` that will let you iterate over the items in the zip file, and an extension method `ExtractToDirectory`. The ZipFile class has static methods to create, open and extract files from a zip file.

Comment: can you please check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873451/unable-to-get-multiple-entries-in-selectentries-of-dotnetzip) and give an answer if possible