# unable to get multiple entries in SelectEntries of DotNetZip

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dotnetzip

I'm trying to use `DotNetZipLib-DevKit-v1.9` in my MVC3 Project to extract the files to a specific folder.

What i want is -- How to add multiple entries in `zip.SelectEntries` method.

Here is my code in controller action:

```
public ActionResult ExtractZip(string fileName, HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
        {
            string zipToUnpack = @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\images.zip";
            string unpackDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();

            using (ZipFile zip1 = ZipFile.Read(zipToUnpack))
            {
                // here, we extract every entry, but we could extract conditionally
                // based on entry name, size, date, checkbox status, etc.  
                var collections = zip1.SelectEntries("name=*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif;");//This shows `0` items in collections

                foreach (var item in collections)
                {
                    item.Extract(unpackDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
                }
            }
            return Json(true);
        }
```

In this line `var collections = zip1.SelectEntries("name=*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif;");` if  i specify only single extension ,it works fine

ex:
`var collections = zip1.SelectEntries("name=*.gif");` this works good

I've also seen SelectEntries method [here](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/Silverlight/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsSL5.Compression.v12.2~Infragistics.Compression.ZipFile~SelectEntries%28String%29.html), but it doesn't help though

How to add multiple entries ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i could answer my own question.

Inorder to select multiple entries we need to use `OR` and to select multiple entries use the following code:

```
var collections = zip1.SelectEntries("(name=*.jpg) OR (name=*.jpeg) OR (name=*.png) OR (name=*.gif)");

foreach (var item in collections)
{
    item.Extract(unpackDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
}
```